# form panel inside layout window in extjs 3.4

Tags: forms, extjs, layout, extjs3

Can anyone help me in creating a form inside a layout window in extjs 3.4. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpXRQ.jpg)? I tried using `Ext.Formpanel` but it shows error.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    // tabs for the center
    var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
        region: 'center',
        margins: '3 3 3 0', 
        activeTab: 0,
        defaults: {
            autoScroll: true
        },
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Movie Grid',
            },
            {
                title: 'Movie Description',
            },
            {
                title: 'Nested layout',
            },
            {
                title: 'The bomb',
            }
        ]
    });

    // Panel for the west
    var nav = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Movie Information Form',
        region: 'west',
        split: true,
        width: 200,
        collapsible: true,
        margins: '3 0 3 3',
        cmargins: '3 3 3 3',
    });

    var win = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'Button',
        closable: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 350,
        //border: false,
        plain: true,
        layout: 'border',
        items: [
            nav,
            tabs
        ]
    });

    win.show(this);
});
```

This is the js file  for creating a layout window. I need to create a form inside "movie information form".

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id var simple=new Ext.FormPanel(

Comment: Well, you are probably missing a `:` somewhere in your code or have another syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved error in your code.Please check & reply.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2750

I have removed **this** which was passed to show() of window.

Comment: Please elaborate. What did you do? What is different?

Comment: She passed this as param to show(), which was breaking as this was browser's window object.I removed it else code was fine,just added few labels.

Comment: Please edit your answer. It does not provide sufficient information on the solution.

Comment: Please tell me precisely what information you want. I don't understand why you digging into this too much when i have provided enough clarity over this answer ?

Comment: Now it is sufficient. 'I have solved your error' is not a sufficient answer as it provides no actual information about the solution. If you only post a link to the fiddle, all the source is off-site and could be removed in the future. That's why you should always post the relevant code straight into your question or answer. Also in the fiddle you would have to search, what is the difference from the original code.